# Adding a new column on a table, based on if there is a match with another column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables

Table 1 has names and modified names
Table 2 has just names

How can I add to table 2, these modified names.

So I have COMPANY1$$$ company1 in table one and COMPANY1$$$ in table 2, and I want to add all corresponding modified names based on correspondence in table 1 (so in this case, in the new column in table 2 there should be company1 now added)

Comment: You are repeating information. It's better to have one table with names and 'modified names', and have both tables refer to that.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your requirement. Perhaps posting some sample data, and the results you're after will help here. Posting your attempt(s) to solve the problem will also help us understand your goals.

Comment: What you are describing is poor database design and will cause you many problems in the future.  Do some research on [Data Normalisation](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) to avoid problems like this altogether.